# Golang lua-script like runs on GAE

Tags: google-app-engine, lua, go

I am looking for a solution for a script language like lua to use with Go application running on GAE. I have found golua and luar projects and planned to use them as the solution.

However, once I ran them on GAE environment, I encountered

```
"o-app-builder: Failed parsing input: parser: bad import "unsafe" in 
github.com/stevedonovan/luar/luar.go"
```

I was confused but finally found that apparently GAE trimmed unsafe package out for a reason. Since luar and golua need the package, I think I have to find a new solution for this.

Is there any way to use luar and golua on GAE? If it is not possible, are there any alternative script languages that will run on GAE environment?

Answer (score 0):

The just announced [Managed VMs](https://developers.google.com/cloud/managed-vms) will allow you to run App Engine applications on Compute Engine virtual machines. This allows access to the full range of libraries, filesystems and sockets. As of today (April 20th, 2014) Managed VMs are in Limited Preview, so you'll need to fill out [the form](http://cloud.google.com/r/managed-vms) here to get access.